# Things don't appear to be working at the moment.Please try again later

Tags: paypal, xamarin.forms, paypal-sandbox, express-checkout

I have implemented paypal integration in my mobile app. I am using Rest APIs. It was working fine before a month but suddenly stops working with the following error message :
**Things don't appear to be working at the moment.Please try again later.**
I am getting this error when I try to login in with my sandbox credentials.

Here is my JSON :

```
{
"intent":"sale",
"redirect_urls":{
"return_url":"https://www.google.com/",
"cancel_url":"https://www.google.com/"
},
"payer":{
"payment_method":"paypal",
"payer_info":null
},
"transactions":[
{
"amount":{
"total":"45.9",
"currency":"AUD",
"details":{
"subtotal":"45.9",
"tax":"0",
"shipping":"0"
}
},
"item_list":{
"items":[
{
"quantity":"1",
"name":"Stainless Braided Hose Black",
"price":"45.9",
"currency":"AUD",
"description":"Description not available",
"tax":"0"
}
],
"shipping_address":{
"recipient_name":"Harry p",
"line1":"104, pavan",
"line2":"Shahibaug",
"city":"Ahm",
"country_code":"AU",
"postal_code":"124536",
"phone":"252253656",
"state":"Guj"
}
},
"description":null
}
]
}
```

Comment: Please tell me what I have done wrong and yeah don't down vote if you don't know the answer

Comment: Maybe the problem is shipping_address... `country_code` says AU but `postal_code` are 6 digits... Isn't 4 digits the max in AU?

Comment: @DennisSchröer Thanks for the reply but I have tried wth four digits , still the same error.